# ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run the docker-compose command I found an error on my ubuntu system.
[image: permission error]

### My docker-compose file

[image: Cdocker-compose]

Tell me how to solve this error and if any suggestions give.

Comment: why you want `root` user?

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @3760216 when I run the `docker-compose up -d` command in the terminal I face the same error.

` rajdeepsingh@officialrajdeepsingh:/media/rajdeepsingh/79215e78-8cd9-40b7-8109-9e6a38985a37/ghostLocal/dev$ docker-compose  up -d
ERROR: .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'`

Answer (score 7):

This permission issue is because by default docker daemon runs as root, and you are running as non-root user.

To fix the permission error, use following commands:

```
 sudo groupadd docker
 sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then logout and login again or you can simply run the following command to make the changes instantly

```
newgrp docker
```

Learn more about it on [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

this worked for me

credit: https://feitam.es/how-to-fix-in-docker-and-docker-compose-the-error-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-in-the-fastest-way-and-possibly-unorthodox/

Comment: Observe the warning in the comments of this identical answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71863594/20571