# Docker: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I got this when I was running docker-compose

```sh
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=iramiro-api.jar&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Running docker compose
[6099] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 403, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 966, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You  just need to run this command, it saved my day

```sh
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Anyone who can access the Docker socket can pretty trivially root the entire system; think carefully before you do this.  The socket does not need to be executable, and making anything both executable and world-writable is usually a considered a no-no (so consider mode 0666 for world-writable or 0755 for executable but never 0777).

Comment: Brilliant answer

Comment: This answer works for Ubuntu

Comment: @DavidMaze 666 works, 755 does not the trick to get it running. Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: To reiterate: making the socket world-accessible at all opens your machine up to local compromise.  Think carefully before making the permissions more lenient than 0660.